# Looping over dataflow in ADF

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I am currently transferring 82 tables from SAP to an Azure SQL server. This is done via Azure data factory via. a data flow. im using A CDC connector to be able to do this. which is the reason for the dataflow and not a copy activity. My setup is as follows:

I have a dictionary with 82 tables to which there is a key-value relationship where key refers to the name in SAP , and value is the tablename i want in the database. I use this dictionary in a loop that loops over a data flow that dynamically loads the tables into my SQL server.
[image]

[image]

This has generally worked well, but I have used a CDC connector as a linked service to make this possible.

The problem is that I have no way to project the schemas continuously, so I let them drift in the first place. This has resulted in some funny formats and inappropriate null values.

It is possible to manually project the schemas one at a time, but when I have 82 tables, it will take a very long time to load them one at a time.

so the question is, if it is possible to dynamically project these schemas every loop?

[image]

Comment: ADF dataflow imports projection automatically. It doesn't require to import manually for every dataflow run.

Comment: Could you stop importing projection manually and then run the pipeline dynamically and check?

Comment: I have done this before, and this will cast the types to int instead of Strings, which will remove '00000..' etc. in front of the values.

Comment: It is not possible to import projection dynamically for each run.  Just to understand more about your work, Could you explain why do you use dataflow?

Comment: Im using dataflow, since its the connector i got to work after trying several different types of integrations. this connector is not supported in a regular copy activity, which is why i had to use dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface saying that I do not have any experience using SAP, so this may need to be adapted.
It should be possible, though, by first creating a new table/view which maps the name of the source-table, the name of the source columns, and the target data-type together, similar to this:
[image]
[image]

The table-specific subsection would then be loaded via query (mind the double quotes)
[image] in an Inline-Source and written to a Cache-Sink:

[image]

By setting the Sink's key column to 'source_column', you are then able to call the lookup() function with the column's name as parameter into a DerivedColumn block. Note, that the schema has to be loaded into the map-source's projection first.

[image]

[image]